# rails+rspec+capybara testing edit resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have a test case:

```
#spec/features/post_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Posts" do
  subject { page }

  describe "edit" do

    post=FactoryGirl.create(:post)
    puts post.valid?
    puts post_path(post.id)
    puts post.id

    before { visit edit_post_path(post.id) }
    it {should have_content('Editing')}
    it {current_path.should == edit_post_path(post.id)}

  end
end
```

I have a problem with the generation of URL by route system:

```
$rspec spec/features/posts_spec.rb 
true
81
FF

Failures:

  1) Posts edit 
     Failure/Error: before { visit edit_post_path(post.id) }
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts", :locale=>81, :id=>nil, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
     # ./spec/features/2posts_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Posts edit 
     Failure/Error: before { visit edit_post_path(post.id) }
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts", :locale=>81, :id=>nil, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
     # ./spec/features/2posts_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00592 seconds
2 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/2posts_spec.rb:15 # Posts edit 
rspec ./spec/features/2posts_spec.rb:16 # Posts edit 

Randomized with seed 6503
```

As you can see, the `id` param is not present in the generate link, and the locale param have the `id` param! 
I have no idea. This is very Unattended behavior.

UPDATE: 
I have tried to use `post` instead `post.id` in `edit_post_path`.
This is the result:

```
$rspec spec/features/posts_spec.rb 
true
83
FF

Failures:

  1) Posts edit 
     Failure/Error: before { visit edit_post_path(post) }
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts", :locale=>#<Post id: 83, title: "Vel Voluptas Veniam Ea Neque", autor: "Christina Rogahn", img_path: "Ut Iste Dolore", body: "Adipisci cupiditate eum eum deleniti facilis. Itaqu...", created_at: "2013-10-28 17:26:30", updated_at: "2013-10-28 17:26:31", email: "candelario@abernathy.name", user_id: 1>, :id=>nil, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
     # ./spec/features/2posts_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Posts edit 
     Failure/Error: before { visit edit_post_path(post) }
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"posts", :locale=>#<Post id: 83, title: "Vel Voluptas Veniam Ea Neque", autor: "Christina Rogahn", img_path: "Ut Iste Dolore", body: "Adipisci cupiditate eum eum deleniti facilis. Itaqu...", created_at: "2013-10-28 17:26:30", updated_at: "2013-10-28 17:26:31", email: "candelario@abernathy.name", user_id: 1>, :id=>nil, :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
     # ./spec/features/2posts_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00532 seconds
2 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/features/2posts_spec.rb:14 # Posts edit 
rspec ./spec/features/2posts_spec.rb:15 # Posts edit 

Randomized with seed 32039
```

this is my routes.rb file:

```
#config/routes.rb
SitoNegozio::Application.routes.draw do
  scope "(:locale)", locale: /it|en/ do

  devise_for :users , controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks"}

  resources :users
  resources :posts do
    resources :msgs
  end

  root :to => 'static_pages#index'

  end
end
```

***SOLVED:***

```
#https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/255#issuecomment-24698753
  config.before(:each, type: :feature) do
    default_url_options[:locale] = I18n.default_locale
  end
```

Comment: Please post the relevant part of your routes file.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone getting similar errors.

It is also worth noting that you could get `missing required keys: [:id]` if you don't set your edit method's instance in your controller, so it should be like so:

```
def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

And your feature method would look something like:

```
background do
  @post = Post.create!(:name => 'Testing')
end

visit edit_post_path(@post)
fill_in 'post_name', with: 'Testing Article'
click_button 'Update Post'
```

Your view would look something like so:

```
<%= form_for :post, url: post_path(@post), method: :patch do |form| %>
    <%= @post.errors.full_messages %>
  <%= form.label :name %>
  <%= form.text_field :name %>
  <%= form.submit "Update Post" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing,

```
visit edit_post_path(post.id)
```

Remove the `.id` and try doing:

```
visit edit_post_path(post)
```

Comment: I have just tried, the result is the same: in params locale i have the full post object

Comment: Yes same error. Now i m going to show you the error by editing the original post

Comment: also can you post your routes.rb file